# Initializing an array of structs when no explicit constructor is provided

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, initialization

If I have a struct:

```
struct S { int x = 0, y = 0; };
```

Then, is it OK to initialize an array of such structs like this?

```
S s[5] = {};
```

so that `x` and `y` in each struct is 0? So, do `x` and `y` become a part of the implicit constructor? And if yes, do I need the `= {};` then at all?

Comment: You don't need the `= {}` in this case, default initialized `S` have their `x` and `y` set to `0`. In the case of, say `int arr[5] = {}`, the `= {}` is essential

Comment: Without `= {}` you get [default initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) as mentioned by @PasserBy, but with `= {}` you get [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) starting with c++14 and (I think) [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) in c++11.

Comment: @Holt great, thank you for the links!